# How to change default image uploaded path change on CKFinder[CKEditor] using php

Tags: php, ckeditor

I have to use CKEditor where using CKFinder use to uploaded images how to change default uploaded path.

How to change default browse path.

I spent lot of time on this, any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean for the FileUpload dialog's default path? Or the default path to save the uploads in your server?

Comment: Both.

Actually i want customized folder structured. 
example: If i have three folder on server how uploaded particular folder.

Comment: Ok, How to change default server path only let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but have you tried adding the following lines to your config.js file?

`config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/some/path/on/server";`

and

`config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/some/path/on/server";`

Here is the documentation on the different variables you can use:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserBrowseUrl