# to set custom path for image upload in ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

Here, we are defining path for image upload as like in `config.js` file ckeditor,

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

        config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
        config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
        config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
        config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
        config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
        config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '../resource/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';

};
```

But if we want to set custom path to upload an image for add record and edit record, how can we define that?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163047/how-to-change-default-image-uploaded-path-change-on-ckfinderckeditor-using-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163047/how-to-change-default-image-uploaded-path-change-on-ckfinderckeditor-using-php) You might need visit this question please. it might right.